# PHP variable that get +1 at every appearance

Tags: php, variables

I want to replace this code:

```
$html=<<<EOF

    <p>{${$var[i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[i+1]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[i+2]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[i+3]}[name]}</p>

EOF;
```

with something like this:

```
$html=<<<EOF

    <p>{${$var[new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[new_i]}[name]}</p>

EOF;
```

and preserve functionality of the first piece of code.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: YNT -- please don't put solution in your question. just vote up, and choose what you feel is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Neal OK. I just have to wait 15 minutes to be able to accept an answer.

Comment: but that doesn't mean you should change your question :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post-Increment to the rescue!

```
$html=<<<EOF

    <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>

EOF;
```

---

Although if you are just going to display `$html` right after this, it might be better to do:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $max_i; ++$i):?>
<p><?php echo ${$var[$i]}[name] ?></p>
<?php endfor;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is where the incrementor would come in.

`$i++` will increment the value by one after any action is taken.

`++$i` will increment the value by one before any action is taken.

```
 $html=<<<EOF

     <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
     <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
     <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>
     <p>{${$var[$i++]}[name]}</p>

EOF;
```

Example:

```
$i = 0;
echo $i++; // echo's 0

$i = 0;
echo ++$i; // echo's 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass in `i++` so that it increments every time it appears.

Answer (score -2):

```
$new_i = 0;

$html=<<<EOF

    <p>{${$var[$new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[++$new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[++$new_i]}[name]}</p>
    <p>{${$var[++$new_i]}[name]}</p>

EOF;
```

Using `++` to the left of a variable will increment the value by one before that variable is used.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame, notice that in the OP question and in the "good" answers, all the lines are the same. One of your lines is not like the others.

Comment: @Marcus, not even that.. What exactly are you incrementing? `new_i`? That's not even a variable. You would get a syntax error.

Comment: @sixeightzero `new_i` is the OP's variable and could be [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php).

Comment: @MarcusAdams The original `new_i` is set the following lines increments by `1` before being used.

Comment: .. `new_i` != `$new_i`. You need to be very clear on your syntax.

Comment: @sixeightzero Are you aware of the existence of defined variables? Please RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php. I am using the OP's code.

Comment: You should look at your code and understand why it would fail before giving bad advice.

Comment: @sixeightzero Still waiting for your affirmation that these are indeed not defined variables, seriously what am I missing here?

Comment: The reason it's a "bad" answer is that you have the first call different than the subsequent calls, when it can very easily be done more elegantly with an i++ (as this will return i before incrementing). You also used new_i, which was originally intended to be the new variable that would increment on its own. It just seems a little silly, and could have been thought out better.

Comment: Please take your advice and RTFM. Once you DEFINE a constant, it is CONSTANT. Which means you cannot change the value!! This means, you cannot do `++CONSTANT` or `CONSTANT++` as it would be changing the value of a constant.

Comment: @sixeightzero I stumbled on that as well. Fixed my answer. I only used the original OP's code which I assumed was functional. ASS U ME , etc.

Comment: +Upvote for documenting the issue when trying to reassign a value of a constant.

Comment: @Recursed I think left sided increments are more elegant in this case. Commenting on code elegance is a little silly though.